# RFID/NFC Tag get data from wordpress MySQL

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, lcd, rfid, networking

I have a local workshop for students to teach them 3D printing/woodworking
I want to know if its possible to create **RFID/NFC tags using wordpress data from MySQL or HTTP/HTTPS**.

***Web Scenario*** :

I have a wordpress website where I setup a gamefication plugin.
Each time a student takes a quiz/posts on forum he gets a "x" number of points that are accumulated on his profile.

I want to know if I can get a RFID/NFC tag to get that number of points.
Each member has a RFID/NFC tag card and with that card he can get access to different things around the workshop .

***Workshop Scenario :***

**For each tool there will be a lock , RFID/NFC reader and a LCD display screen.**

**When a student want to access that tool he needs a number of points on the wordpress gamefication script that are transfered to the RFID/NFC card.**

If he has the needed points a text on the LCD screen will appear with something like " **You have access to this tool**" and the tool will be unlocked .

Else if the user doesn't meet the needed points the LCD screen will show "**You don't have the needed points for this tool, please visit [URL] to get more info**" and the tool will stay locked.

---

> **I need only info if this is possible, not the way to do it.**
>
> ***[ In case you are kind to hand me some guides on where to start to will be great! ]***

---

Thanks and waiting to see if this is possible!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell it's absolutely possible but will take some considerable development time and around $30-$70 of hardware per NFC terminal. Please note I would strongly not recommend this as a first project as it has a lot of individual components that all have to work together flawlessly and each is different. Properly done this will be complex software and hardware wise although more so from the hardware side of things.

Hardware wise you need/terminal:

- **LCD display** (I would recommend segmented for simplicity and cost)
- **Wifi or ethernet shield/breakout** and ethernet cable if the board is not wifi compatible
- **Arduino** (MKR1000 has wifi built in), Feather (Adafruit's boards that are frequently Arduino software compatible and have many shields available and guides written on how to use them), or cheap Arduino knock off (preferably not this option as giving money to arduino.cc, Adafruit, or other designers is important if we want new boards regularly)
- **NFC breakout** or shield (Google/DuckDuckGo/Bing RFID-RC52 for an economical option, they're ~$4 on Ebay)
- **Power supply** corresponding to the requirements of the chosen board + shields + breakouts
- **NFC tags**
- **Lock** able to be unlocked by a servo. If you expect security in absence of supervising shop manager (aka just to be safe, assume dishonesty in people using the shop) from this system, the locks need to be better than a Masterlock as those are insecure to even simple soda can shims. The rotary masterlocks can also be reduced to 100 possible combinations and then the combo can be brute forced easily from there so if you get a rotary based lock system make sure the assembly covering the dial is not easily removed.
- **Servo or stepper** powerful enough to actuate locks
- **Servo or stepper driver breakout board**

Then you'd just want to have the public key (note I don't mean a "public key" in the general cryptography sense but on that subject, you do want the key encrypted) to the user stored on the NFC tag and then use the arduinos+electronics to read the tags and see point values. User data from wordpress could be downloaded periodically to the boards so the individual checks don't use network resources and the system works offline.

Comment: Little OLED display (0.96") are available with I2C and SPI interfaces are more versatil, take less footprint and power. And instead of Arduino + WiFi shield, why not NodeMCU?